# Creating a dynamic download page based on directory

Tags: php, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm cobbling together a simple website in Bootstrap 3 to serve files on an isolated LAN, I'm not a web developer by trade so apologies if this is a bit of a stupid question:

*Is there an easy way to have a webpage dynamically populate with files from a given directory?*

For instance, if I just dumped a load of files in `/var/www/downloads/`, could I have them appear as links in a `<ul>` on a page?

I know something like this could be written in PHP or I could get people to connect to an FTP service, just wondering if such a solution already exists.

Comment: You can enable directory listing in your virtual host/.htaccess with `Options +Indexes` (Read more: https://support.tigertech.net/directory-index)

Comment: also: https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/

Comment: Great resources, I'd seen how [Ubuntu](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/releases/17.04/release/) handles their directory listings but didn't know the extent to which it could be customised. I'll look into embedding this in my page.